# Importing one module from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am importing one module from another module so I am using below syntax

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    try:
        print("sorry We can't Let use this module To another Framework :")
    except Exception:
        print("yup")
    sys.exit(0)
```

How to stop preventing importing one module from another module so that whenever I call previous module it will run `sys.exit(status)` and module import process will fail?

Comment: You can't really prevent people from importing your module. Worst case scenario is that they have to open your file with a text editor and remove the import check...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#think i found better solution myself 
#so what if i write operation stuffs after calling main() #instead of writing those in main method like an example

def main() :
    return 

if  __name__=='__main__' :
     main() #calling main
   #todo operation stuffs#####

#Note: So if this module call by another module then it won't provide any operation stuffs just because main function has nothing to return. But in this module after calling main rest of the operations will start executing
```

Comment: "if __name__ == '__main__'" means that the library is the main module. So what you wrote as explanation for your code snippet is wrong. In your code snippet the module would return nothing when running the file directly and when importing it, it will run everything except the code inside the if statement.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you right the solution would be as follows:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("didn't get imported")
    # do some magic
else:
    print("got imported")
    exit(1)
```